# How to make onclick event occur before onblur?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have 2 elements, an anchor with onclick = "..." and an input with onfocus = "..." The anchor is toggled by the input button, so when the button is in focus, the anchor is displayed and when it loses focus the anchor is hidden. Is there a way I can access the onclick event from the anchor without the onblur occurring first?

```
input(type="radio", name="sample", value=str(sample['id']),
     id="S"+str(sample['id']),onfocus = 'javascript:toggleVisibility("%stoggle");' 
     % sample['id'], onblur = 'toggleVisibility("%stoggle");' % sample['id'])

a("edit", id = "%stoggle" % str(sample['id']), style="display:none; float:right;
   padding-left:10px; text-decoration:none;", href='do something')
```

Comment: What do you mean by access? You want to fire onClick event or just get the function? And what do you need it for? There might me better solution...

Comment: I'd just like to be able to change the value displayed with the radio button. As it is now, the href address or code won't execute because the onblur happens before the href fires. Is there a quick way I can just get that to happen?

Comment: Does it work now or still facing issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the `onmousedown`  instead of `onclick`.

Comment: It seems like the onblur is still happening first

Comment: What about to call a function with setTimeout? So after blur it takes about 500ms to do the toggleVisiblity (for code example I need to know your toggleVisiblity code)

Comment: setTimeout works. I had tried it before but I was using 0.5 rather than 500 as argument. Thanks all

Comment: np :) Yeah, setTimeout and setInterval need ms as parameters.